# Why does this code throw an error when used inside the controller, but not the view?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have the following model:

```
class User

include DataMapper::Resource

property :id,     Serial
property :name,   String, required: true
property :email,   String, required: true, unique: true
property :password_digest, Text
attr_reader :password
attr_accessor :password_confirmation

validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_format_of :email, as: :email_address

has n, :victories
```

This works fine, and allows for people to sign-up to the website. However, I then defined the following route:

```
get 'users/all' do
  @users = User.all
  @users.each do |user|
    user.name
  end
end
```

Now, the application will still run but when I attempt to visit '/users/all', I am greeted with "This site can't be reached" and the following terminal error:

```
ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Body yielded non-string value #<User @id=1 @name="Iain K" @email="test@googlemail.com" @password_digest=<not loaded>>
```

When I wrap this logic in a view however, it works:

```
get 'users/all' do
  @users = User.all
  erb(:'users/all')
end
```

Inside users/all.erb:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
  Name: <%= user.name %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Why is this?

All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the day, your controller needs to return a string. `erb :'users/all'` returns a string.

Let's back up a sec and look at your existing code though, specifically this:

```
  @users.each do |user|
    user.name
  end
```

The block here basically has no effect; `each` does *not* return a modified array (maybe you were looking for `map`?)

Although you already have the right idea to move this logic into the view, I'm just pointing out that the original code was wrong in more ways than one.

Comment: I realise I used `.each` incorrectly here. If I said `print user.name`, that would be fine though, right? (I'm not saying it would have resolved this particular error). Thanks for your help, Max.

Comment: Yeah if you wanted to print each line that would make sense. But its not clear what you were trying to do in the original code.